# Display html content only in home page

Tags: php, html

I am developing a site, I was wondering if I could use `PHP` in a generic way in order to show a div on the home page, but no on any other page. The code I have so far,

```
<?php
    if host == 'http://domain.com/'; echo {
        This should only be shown on the homepage http://domain.com but not on domain.com/directory or sub.domain.com/ !
    } else {
    };
?>
```

Comment: The same php file is serving from multiple different domains?

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes its the header file and i need it to automatically add and remove the div based on the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $match_domains = array('google.com','www.google.com');
    if(in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $match_domains) {
        echo 'show on my domain!';
    }
?>
```

Using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] we compare it to our desired domain.
We use in_array to search $match_domains for the current domain. If it's in the array, we show our text...Anything else, we ignore.

```
<?php
    $domain = str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']); // Strip out www.
    $match_domains = array('google.com');
    if(in_array($domain, $match_domains) {
        echo 'show on my domain!';
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks this works but how would I stop the content from showing in directory's

Comment: It's an absolute comparison, so it won't work on anything but the root domain. Even www., so you could do instead this (editing, one moment).

Comment: yes i understand this but when i force www. on my server it forces it on my subdomains e.g www.business.domain.com and www.myaccount.domain.com

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding your question. Also if you wanted, you could strip out the www. so you're list is only main domains.

Comment: Its ok i resolved the problem with my .htaccess I just forced the domain with non-www rewrite Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the home page why don't you check the file name

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/index.php") {
    echo "<div>Content</div>";
}
```